# Running CouchDB Futon on Remote Server

Tags: ssh, couchdb, ssh-tunnel, couchdb-futon

i using mac os..

i tried

> > ssh -fNg -L 5985:127.0.0.1:5984 wawansetiawan@192.168.1.249

but there's command like this:

bind: Address already in use
channel_setup_fwd_listener: cannot listen to port: 5985
Could not request local forwarding.

any one can help me??

Answer (score 2):

This is nothing to do with couchdb, it's an ssh question. ssh cannot open port 5985 because there's already something running on your local machine listening on that port. Use a different port or close whatever process has port 5985 open.

Answer (score 0):

An application/Process is already running on your machine with port 5985. Use a different port or close whatever application/process has port 5985 & start the ssh tunnel again.

Try to use different port

```
ssh -fNg -L 5986:127.0.0.1:5984 wawansetiawan@192.168.1.249
```

Or You can kill application/process has port 5985.

```
netstat -nap | grep 5985
kill -9 <pid-of-5985-process>
```

Start the ssh tunnel again.
    ssh -fNg -L 5985:127.0.0.1:5984 wawansetiawan@192.168.1.249